# Copy one file into multiple names

Tags: linux, cp

I want to copy one file into other names:

```
cp server4.conf server{5..8}.conf
cp: target 'server8.conf' is not a directory
```

Why is this command not working?

Answer (score 0):

`cp` takes either a source file and a target file, or multiple source files and a target directory.
Extract from the man (UNIX cp but I believe it is the same on Linux):

```
SYNOPSIS
     cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
     cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

Your command gets substituted in

```
cp server4.conf server5.conf server6.conf server7.conf server8.conf
```

So indeed `server8.conf` is expected to be the target directory for you files `server4.conf` to `server7.conf`